# How to run two multiple thread simultaneously in objective C?

Tags: objective-c

I need to run two threads simultaneously, but I am not getting how to do so.

I start thread:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(MyNewThread:) toTarget:[CMyClass class] withObject:nil];    

-(void)MyNewThread:(id)param{
    NSAutoreleasePool *Pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *strSwitcher = @"myCommand";

    const char * cstrSwitcher = [strSwitcher UTF8String];
    system(cstrSwitcher);
    [Pool release];
}
```

and some other system command I want to send on other thread. When I send one system command prompt changes.(e.g. myCommand> ).

Now when I start another thread then that command only works when previous thread was stopped.

Anyone can help me??

Comment: sorry I didn't mention this. i already run two threads simultaneously.But know I write different- different system commands on different thread.

Comment: When I run 1 thread, another thread didn't work untill I stop previous thread.

Comment: Please post some code showing how exactly you're trying to run multiple threads at once.

Comment: 13 questions and 9 have answers and you haven't accepted any. Not looking good, mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By taking into account the info in your comment on the OP, I assume you want to call `system()` from multiple thread simultaneously.

Unfortunately, that cannot work because when you call `system()`, your application waits for a signal that is sent as soon as the child process exits. Because signals don't know anything about the threads in your application, `system()` cannot be run from multiple threads simultaneously.

**Thanks for JeremyP to point into the direction of NSTask in the comments!**

The alternative is to use the `NSTask`.

`NSTask` uses `fork()` to create a child process and calls `waitpid()` in the parent and `execve()` (or one of its siblings) in the child process. Using the macros defined in `<sys/wait.h>`, the child's return value is retrieved after it finishes. This way, multiple child process can be launched without blocking other threads. You can either do all that yourself, or just use the simple `NSTask` class.

Comment: I just added a little bit more detail about using `execve()` in my post. If my answer helps, please accept it.

Comment: Rather than use fork/exec/in Cocoa, use NSTask.

Comment: Of course! Using `NSTask` is much simpler. Silly me... Just the other week I implemented that functionality in another environment and looked at the GNUSTEP NSTask implementation for hints. That actually does what I described above. I added the `NSTask` stuff to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using Hungarian notation (Windows picked that up back in the Win32 days, but dropped it in .NET) as that just complicates things. rename 'Pool' to 'pool', and 'strSwitcher' to 'switcher'. Now, just call system([switcher UTF8String]); instead of that extra variable. On top of this, remove the NSAutoreleasePool, and use the new @autoreleasepool { } definition, enclosing your code in it. Here's how it looks now.

```
- (void)myNewThread:(id)param {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *switcher = @"myCommand";
        system([switcher UTF8String]);
    }
}
```

And if you'd like to switch to NSTasks to be able to run multiple executables, here's how it goes: (I also changed the method a bit.)

```
- (void)executeTaskAtPath:(NSString *)path withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSTask *task = [launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:arguments];
        [task waitUntilExit]; // This blocks the thread.
    }
}
```

To find out if the task was terminated successfully, register for a NSTaskDidTerminateNotification at [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter].

Comment: Wow, did I dig up an old post. My bad.

Comment: Is it possible to use `NSTask` in iOS?